# use actionlistener to call void function in same class

Tags: java, swing, methods, actionlistener, void

I have problem to use action listener to call function void in same class.

example..
code:

```
public class Product extends JPanel {

    JButton add;
    JPanel pAdd;
    JLabel test;
    JFrame frame;

    public Product() {
        add = new JButton("Add Product");
        add.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());

        add(add);
    }

    public void panelAdd(){
        pAdd = new JPanel();
        pAdd.add(new JLabel("try"));
        add(pAdd);

    }

    private class ButtonListener implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            panelAdd();
        }
    }
}
```

How to make call the `panelAdd` void method?

Comment: Making Product static, or creating a constructor for ButtonListener with the instance of Product to keep it as a field

Comment: I don't get your problem. The class compiles. So you can call your void method like this! So, what is your real question on this?

Comment: bobbel.. yes, the class compile.. but my gui does not appear.. at first i run the public product method.. then when i click the "add" button, i want it to run panelAdd method.. but it does not appear..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you add components to visible `JFrame`/`JPanel`/other components, you neet to call `revalidate()` and`repaint()` methods after adding. Change your `panelAdd()` like next:

```
public void panelAdd(){
    pAdd = new JPanel();
    pAdd.add(new JLabel("try"));
    add(pAdd);
    revalidate();
    repaint();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you put

```
 System.out.println("hi");
```

to

```
public void panelAdd(){
  System.out.println("hi");
   pAdd = new JPanel();
   pAdd.add(new JLabel("try"));
   add(pAdd);
```

}

you will see hi printed to your console , your code are working, but you have problem in Layout .